# PHP problem with include

Tags: php

```
<?
$dir=scandir('/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/');

foreach($dir as $file){
        if($file!='.' && $file!='..' && $file!='index.php'){
                $choice=$dir[rand(0, count($dir) - 1)];
                include($choice);
        }
}
?>
```

I have a little problem with that code. Of course it is working on some files but it is still trying to include index.php, .. and .
Can sameone help me with solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split Your code into two parts: first one to prepare array of good files; second to include random file:

```
$allfiles = scandir('/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/');

$goodfiles = array();
foreach ($allfiles as $file) {
  if($file!='.' && $file!='..' && $file!='index.php'){
    $goodfiles[] = $file;
  }
}

$choicenfile = $goodfiles[rand(0, count($goodfiles) - 1)];
// As I understant You want to include only one file, not all;
include($choicenfile);
```

Now You can even extract this code to methods or functions

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply the full path, your trying to include the file from the location of the script.

Change this:

```
include($choice);
```

to:

```
include('/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/'.$choice);
```

I wouldn't do it this way, but it should work.

Comment: Warning: include(/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs) [function.include]: failed to open stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device in /home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/index.php on line 8

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/..' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php') in /home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/index.php on line 8



So it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if you want to include all files in randomized order or just one random file of the given folder, so I have included both in the solution - just delete what you don't need:

```php
function filter_includes($incfile) {
    return !in_array($incfile, array(".", "..", "index.php"));
}

$dirPath = '/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/';
$dir = array_filter(scandir($dirPath), "filter_includes");

// include all files in randomized order
shuffle($dir);
foreach($dir as $file) {
    include($dirPath . $file);
}

// include one random file
include($dirPath . $dir[rand(0, count($dir) - 1)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of the rand in `$choice=$dir[rand(0, count($dir) - 1)];`?

Because right now it's just including a random file in your array.

You should change your code to something like:

```
$dir=scandir('/home/crusty/www/crusty.bshellz.pl/htdocs/404/');

foreach($dir as $file){
    if($file!='.' && $file!='..' && $file!='index.php'){
        include($file);
    }
}
```